# Error: google-backup-and-sync: It seems there is already an App

Tags: homebrew

I'm using `brew upgrade --cask --greedy`. Everything is fine except for "google-back-and-sync". Brew says:

```
Error: google-backup-and-sync: It seems there is already an App at '/usr/local/Caskroom/google-backup-and-sync/latest/Backup and Sync.app'.
```

I don't understand what the problem is and how I can solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To address this, I just did

```
rm -r /usr/local/Caskroom/google-photos-backup-and-sync/latest/Backup\ and\ Sync.app

brew reinstall google-photos-backup-and-sync
```

Comment: Thanks!

I reinstalled the pack.